# Считывание нескольких ссылок с помощью библиотеки Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Есть `EditText`, в который ввожу название футбольной команды, далее эта команда ищется в гугле и со страницы поиска считывается первая ссылка, которая заносится в строковою переменную. И при попытке считать и запарсить данные,находящиеся по ссылке в строковой переменной, происходит ошибка. Если же парсить только одну страницу, то ошибок не возникает. Объясните пожалуйста, каким образом следует парсить несколько страниц, чтобы не возникало ошибок.

Код:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private Button button1;
        private TextView textView1;
        private EditText editText;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        }

        public void ClickMe(View v) {
            MyTask mt = new MyTask();
            mt.execute();
        }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String title;
        String urltext;
        String team;
        String title1;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            team = editText.getText().toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Document doc = null;
            Document doc1 = null;

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com.ua/search?rlz=1C1AVNE_enUA709UA711&ei=3DoAWs_ICY6WsAeIibaIBw&q=myscore+результат+матча+команды+" + team + "+футбол&oq=myscore+результат+матча+команды+" + team + "+футбол&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1.4221.5963.0.6244.8.8.0.0.0.0.303.1096.0j2j2j1.5.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.3.595....0.84mRWpFt5ic").get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (doc != null) {

                Elements text = doc.select(".s");
                title = text.text();
                urltext = title.substring(+0, title.indexOf("К"));
                try {

                    doc1 = Jsoup.connect(urltext).get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (doc != null) {
                    title1 = doc.title();
                } else
                    title1 = "Ошибка";
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            textView1.setText(title1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Допишите стек ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача разрешилась путем добавления https:// к считываемой ссылке, поэтому если у кого то возникнут проблемы с использованием считываемой ссылке, не забудьте добавить https://.